# How many messages an edge module can send to edgeHub?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I am building one use case, where I need to simulate a lot of data from each custom module,  like 500 messages/min, will there be any issues?

will edgeHub handle, 500 messages/custom modules from ten such custom modules at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

EdgeHub, a module that is a part of IoT Edge Runtime, itself does not have any throttling limits. If you have a decent hardware setup or a VM running IoT Edge Runtime, you can easily have 500 messages per second.

The only thing you have to count on are [IoT Hub limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling), as this can limit the upstream communication.

Comment: ok, currently simulator setup I am using each of the simulators modules is sending around 39620 messages in four hours.  i have 10 such containers, the expected messages in the iothub is around 396, 200  * 10  --> 396k messages, but in iothub graph  statistics it showed only 90k messages in last four hour,, this is very stange

Comment: In that case maybe edge hub simulator is not most reliable for high frequency testing. I advise checking the edge hub simulator logs to figure out if upstream is blocked. If it is, check the IoT hub limitations, maybe you need to increase number of iot hub units.

Comment: Or test outside if the simulation environment and make sure it reflects the reality

Comment: in logs, everything seems to be fine, I think its the iothub limit I am using 2*s1 so it should allow 24 messages/sec/unit,  I was checking metrics graphs of iothub , and found its getting received at 6-7/meesge / second which is very strange, ita not even hitting the throttle limit,  in my logs, there are no failure.